# Universal Access Zoom In/Out

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, window-management, accessibility

I have been trying for hours to get the Universal Access Zoom In/Out feature to work. I have used several different key combinations but it just wouldn't work. I got the zoom in to work with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>; however the zoom out key would not work and after rebooting it stopped working altogether.

I would really love to give this OS ago and use it long term so would very much appreciate if someone can advise me on how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Could you please make the question only about one specific topic and create new questions for each other issue?

Comment: Regarding privacy concerns, please read at [Does elementary OS perform any sort of remote data collection?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/does-elementary-os-perform-any-sort-of-remote-data-collection). The safety of PPAs is explained at [Can I safely install any PPA for Ubuntu on elementary?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17/can-i-install-any-ppa-for-ubuntu-safely-on-elementary)

Comment: Apologies, first time ever I have used a forum for help so don’t know the rules….. I normally just install and play about  with the OS to figure out… think I will go back to using Ubuntu for now and come back to eOS in few months time. Thanks for the reply re PPA

Comment: No problem! Another link for you: [How can I view the desktop?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/396/how-can-i-view-the-desktop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, elementary OS has a magnifier that can be used by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out.

Note that <kbd>⌘</kbd> refers to the "Super" key, which on your hardware might have a Windows logo, an Ubuntu logo, or the word "Command".

Comment: Done a fresh  install and its working now! :-) Thank you so much!!