# How to disable recent files in pantheon files?

Tags: system, files

I have changed the settings at **security & privacy** but elementary OS still collects recent files and shows them in **recent** folder, so how would i turn off recent files? Thanks.

Comment: what have you changed in security and privacy? If I turn privacy mode on, the recent folder just shows 'there are no recent files'. 

as a side note, why would you like to disable this feature? as discussed here, elementary doesn't collect any usage data and the security and privacy settings are related to local data only: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/does-elementary-os-perform-any-sort-of-remote-data-collection/1640#1640

Answer (score 2):

If you enable privacy mode like so:

[image: privacy mode]

You'll still see an empty "Recent" link in file manager:

[image: recent file manager]

However it should disappear from the open file dialogue for apps:
[image: open file dialogue]