# Is elementary OS phoning home? Privacy please!

Tags: applications, elementary-website, internet, privacy

When my internet connection is cut off by a misconfigured VPN, immediately a window opens that says it cannot connect to the Internet. When I reconnect to the Internet the window loads elementary OS content. It looks like a elementary OS welcome-window or something like that. But it is not loaded in the browser.
How can I disable this? I do not want any connection besides the programms I use!
Please advise!
Thanks!

Comment: They are trying to get you to donate. I think

Comment: I also have this

Comment: elementary OS is not phoning home: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1442/5748

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an issue with the Captive Portal Assistant. It's a tool installed by default to assist users in wifi networks with a separate login page (e.g. in a hotel). Most likely it (wrongfully) recognizes your connection as "captive network" and tries to assist you (which doesn't work of course, as there is no login page to show). After successful login, it normally displays [`elementary.io`](https://elementary.io) to test the connectivity.

If you don't want this functionality, you can remove the package `capnet-assist`. That being said, elementary OS does not track you in any way. The source code for `elementary.io` is even open source, so you could [check it and make sure it does not track you](https://github.com/elementary/mvp).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think that is exactly what happens. It shows elementary.io afterwards.
No, I will keep that function. No privacy concerns anymore...

Comment: @PeterJones, if you question has been answered please mark the answer that did so.